# Design view problem in xml file : Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

When I run my application, buttons are not displaying(A little part is displaying, that makes feel that something is there), although I scroll down. 
How to solve my problem. Is there any way to set size of textboxes (Where size depends on screen size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @100rabh already said you should really start reading about Android layouts.

Some very good articles by Romain Guy are [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) and of course on his [blog](http://www.curious-creature.org/).

There is also a very good series of articles on Mobiletuts+ called [Android User Interface Design](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/) by Lauren Darcey and Shane Conder.

You should really check that out and then redesign your layout.

Answer (score 2):

Pankaj did you checked the orientation of the root LinearLayout tag ??

All you need to do is change root LinearLayout's orientation to **vertical** & you will see every button in your layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

& please read more about layouts before implementing them.

Comment: I used it but problem is being same.

Comment: pankaj another problem with your layout is that root LinearLayout is not closed so do close it by cutting line 46's </LinearLayout> tag & pasting it at the end of layout

Answer (score 0):

As you're using linear layouts, you can use `android:layout_weight`. If you search, you'll find many examples.